# What happen Windows Azure Portal after MSDN subscription expire.

Tags: azure, msdn

I have MSDN subscription "Visual Studio Professional with MSDN" and I am using Windows Azure using my subscription. I just wonder what happen if my subscription will expire, Can I still use free quota on Windows Azure portal forever? Or I won't able to access portal after my msdn subscription expire.

regards

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to continue to access the Windows Azure Portal after your subscription expires.  When you signed up for the Windows Azure subscription benefits for MSDN it required you to enter a credit card.  Depending on when you signed up the spending cap feature may have been in place, which would mean that you would not have been charged for overages unless you requested the spending cap removed.

Check out information about the [MSDN benefits](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/msdn-benefits/) and the [spending cap information](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/spending-limits/).  Here is [another good article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2011/12/28/windows-azure-trial-account-spending-limit.aspx) as well.

When the subscription completely expires then if you keep your data in there without removing it eventually you will either need to remove the spending cap to pay for that or remove it (all running deployments would have been stopped for you).  I believe they store the data like 90 days after a subscription runs out before completely destroying on their own.

If you are using the Windows Azure Web Sites feature for the Free sites, you should be able to continue to access those sites (based on the quotas) at any time.

You can also request that an Azure Subscription be transitioned from a Trial or MSDN account to a pay as you go account at any time (see the last article above).  Basically you are just removing your spending limit.

Comment: I have contacted Microsoft about moving a website to a different subscription, but that is not possible it seems. I got this developer benefits but cannot use it unless I drop the whole website and re-create it. I also have some old Azure benefits lying around from the action packs we had and I do not have a clue what the benefit is or end date. Managing benefits and subscriptions is hard in the portal

Answer (score 0):

> > I have contacted Microsoft about moving a website to a different subscription, but that is not possible it seems.

Moving a web site from one subscription to another is not the same thing as retaining an MSDN subscription as PAYG after it has expired.